# difference between fixture and dataprovider in yii2

Tags: php, yii2, codeception

What is the difference between dataProvider and fixtures, I understand that both of them provide parameters to their testing function.

Comment: Is this for testing generally or Codeception specifically? I know PHPUnit uses Data Providers, they're triggered using `@comments` in test method docblocks.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the answer is incorrect as the data provider part is messed up.

Data provider feature gets to Codeception from PHPUnit (Codeception is built on top of it).

Fixture defines DB record which will be available in database during the test execution. Fixtures are all cleared up once test completes.

Data provider defines input or data set (in the sense of function arguments) for the test (the method that actually performs the test). Data provider is a method that returns array where each key represents one param for test method.

To declare data provider for a test `@dataProvider` annotation is used in test doc block.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in Yii2 guide

> A data provider is a class implementing
>   yii\data\DataProviderInterface.  It mainly supports retrieving data a
>   a way useful for application need  eg ..paginated and sorted data. 
>   For this are used  often for provide a proper content to  work with
>   data widgets
>
> Fixtures are an important part of testing.
>
> Yii provides a fixture framework that allows you to define your
>   fixtures precisely and use them easily.
>
> In yii you have  a so-called fixture object.  A fixture object
>   represents a particular aspect of a test environment and is an
>   instance of yii\test\Fixture or its child class.
>
> a part of the fixture framework are the fixture data for an
>   ActiveFixture fixture that is usually provided in a file located at 
>   FixturePath/data/TableName.php

So the dataPropvider  are application object for accessing real application data 
fixture are component of testing that use fixture data for testing application

you can take a better explanation in

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-test-fixtures.html
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-providers.html